# How can I run SharePoint Designer 2010 and 2013 on the same machine?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

After installing SharePoint Designer 2013 and MS Office 2013 on my Win7 64-bit laptop, SharePoint Designer 2010 crashes every time I try to open a site. Can SharePoint Designer 2010 and 2013 coexist?

Comment: I don't get a crash but I've been having severe issues with being able to check in and out documents.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can install both versions of SharePoint Designer on the same machine.  They just need to be the same edition (32-bit or 64-bit).

You might be able to fix your current situation by uninstalling both.  Then install designer 2013 first and then designer 2010.  And make sure that both are either 32-bit or 64-bit versions of designer (also needs to be the same edition of Office 2013).

Comment: I'll try reinstalling, but everything is 32-bit already and of course SPD2010 was install 1st.

Comment: How can I set the default Designer to be used ?

Comment: Don't mess with the 64-bit versions of Office or SPD, unless you have a need for a particular obscure feature that is only available in 64-bit.  Installing everything as 32-bit will steer you clear of trouble.

Comment: Works for me on Windows 7 x64/64-bit with both versions of SPD being x32/32-bit. But I also installed SPD 2010 before installing SPD 2013 as hinted elsewhere on the web (http://dimitri.spgurus.com/blogs/2013/11/12/sharepoint-designer-2010-and-2013-side-by-side/).